# Casting and using the result in one line

Tags: c#, wpf, casting

I want to cast WrapPanel

```
wp = (WrapPanel)topSP.Children[0];
wp.Children.Add(txtB1);
```

so that it looks something like that

```
topSP.Children[0](WrapPanel).Add(txtB1);
```

is that possible?

Comment: This 'chaining' of properties and casts can cause a lot of work when chasing null reference and index out of range exceptions. Keep them on separate lines and check for nulls and index ranges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
((WrapPanel)topSP.Children[0]).Children.Add(txtB1);
```

Note that there probably is a better way. But this should work.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can but all this 'chaining' of properties and casts can cause a lot of work when chasing null reference and index out of range exceptions. Keep them on separate lines and check for nulls and index ranges.

So even though this might work:

```
((WrapPanel)topSP.Children[0]).Children.Add(txtB1);
```

It is much safer to do this:

```
if(topSP.Children.Count > 0)
{
    var wrapPanel = topSP.Children[0] as WrapPanel;
    if(wrapPanel != null)
    {
        wrapPanel.Children.Add(txtB1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap cast in parenthesis and you are good to go -

```
((WrapPanel)topSP.Children[0]).Children.Add(txtB1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way of changing the type is this:

```
(topSP.Children[0] as WrapPanel).Children.Add(txtB1);
```

This is not the same as a cast, as if `topSP.Children[0]` is not a `WrapPanel`, this will throw a `NullReferenceException`, as in that case `(topSP.Children[0] as WrapPanel) == null`.

Comment: Oh really? Downvoted? Care to explain, please, why you downvote a perfectly valid answer?

Comment: Although I did not vote on anything (neither yours, nor Rohits) I think you are missing one level of `.Children` according to Paul's two liner.

Comment: @nvoigt Good spot. See you had the same problem :-) Fixed this. However, instead of downvoting a simple comment would have been enough to get it fixed.

Comment: This gives different behaviour to the original so isn't really "another way of writing it".